# Pycharm 2018.1.1, Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5 error - ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu, pip, pycharm

Brand new install of Ubuntu - in fact I have reinstalled so many times that I gave up - and installed this as a VM in VMware Workstation with a Snapshot taken right after a clean install fully patched and updated.

Heres what have done over 50 times over and over to no avail.

Ive installed PIP3, Numpy, Pycharm with the following process:

## Install Java:

Sudo apt-get install default-jre

## Update the system:

Sudo apt-get update

Sudo apt-get -y upgrade

## Install PIP3, numpy, pycharm:

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

Sudo apt-get install python3-numpy

Sudo pip3 install numpy

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

Sudo apt install snapd

sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic

## load pycharm-community:

Customize Pycharm

*Do not import settings

UI Theme:   Darcula

Featured plugins:  None

Complete Customization

*Create New Project = NewProj

```
-> Project Interpreter: New Virtualenv environment

    -> New environment using Virtualelv

    -> Location:   /home/bob/PycharmProjects/NewProj/venv

    -> Base interpreter:  /usr/bin/python3.5

        -> Inherit global site-packages *NOT SELECTED*

        -> Make available to all projects  *NOT SELECTED*
```

->->->-> Creating Virtual Env....

->NewProj
    -> venv

Rightclick venv ->New ->python file:    Lab1.py

Lab1.py:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
S = range(1000)
print(sys.getsizeof(5) * len(S))

D = np.arange(1000)
print(D.size * D.itemsize)
O / P - 14000
```

RUN

```
*/home/bob/PycharmProjects/NewProj/venv/bin/python 
/home/bob/PycharmProjects/NewProj/venv/lab1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/NewProj/venv/lab1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

People have asked me about make sure that PYTHONPATH is configured correctly
I have no clue what that is, how to check it or how to edit it, what to put in it.

This is a clean install.  Shouldnt have to chmod or screw with file rights... etc..

Bout ready to FORMAT and install windows on top of this pile of schmeg.

If anyone can help I'll paypal 50 bucks over.   At this point Im about to give up.

Answer (score 2):

Embarrassing... someone threw me a video link in youtube that nailed it.    PFFFFFFT!!!!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxwB8KBLMcs

In a nutshell - in Pycharm -

File>Settings>Project:Name>Project Interpreter:

Click the + to add a package.

Find numpy in the list

Click OK - and close your way back out to your program....

I spent two days on this....  now I forgot what the hell I was actually trying to accomplish by installing all this crap.

Comment: Just for your info: when you choose to create a virtual environment in pycharm, the code you are running will not use the version of Python you have installed through command line but a new one placed in the venv (virtual environment) subfolder of your project. Therefore, you either need to install numpy in the venv subfolder or select the standard machine interpreter.